База данных SQLITE3 в Тг. Выводит имя пользователя и пароль виде <built-in method strip of str object at 0x...>
Приветствую начал изучать питон недавно. Писал бота в телеграмме который должен был регистрировать пользователя и выводить кто еще зарегистрировался из пользователей. Выводить должен был формате
Имя:
Пароль:
В итоге после Имени и пароля пишет что то типа<built-in method strip of str object at 0x0000020C7ED999F0>Скрин оставлю ниже. Также оставлю часть кода, если что могу скинуть весь код.
Что нужно сделать что бы корректно отображалось имя пользователя и пароль?  
import telebot
import sqlite3
import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
name = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, username varchar(50), password varchar(50))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет я тебя щас зарегестртрую! Скажи своё имя:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)


def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пороль:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_password)


def user_password(message):
    password = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (name, password))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей:', callback_data='users_name'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь зареистрирован!', reply_markup=markup)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    users = cur.fetchall()

    info = ''
    for el in users:
        info += f'Имя: {el[1]}, Пароль: {el[2]}\n'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Что нужно сделать что бы корректно отображалось имя пользователя и пароль? Как исправить?

Изначально записать в базу правильно, например?

Могу вас неправильно понять, Да

Изначально в базе данных что то есть?

Нет, в начале кода создаётся таблица. Создаётся один раз. Могу весь код добавить он на 60 строк

можешь скинуть код, где записываешь данные в бд?

Вангую, что перед записью в базу пытаетесь использовать метод strip, но не вызываете его со скобками, а просто через точку пишете, что-то типа: name.strip. Чтобы метод вызывался, нужно добавить скобки: name.strip()

Я добавил скрин кода  можете посмотреть @Nick

Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

Вставьте код текстом (только токен сотрите). По этому фрагменту кода похоже, что проблему со strip вы поправили (но это не точно, возможно это не весь код), но существующие данные в базе уже испорченные. Если это так - таблицы в базе нужно очистить, после этого уже вводить данные заново.

Завтра попробую последовать вашим совета потом напишу. Код я добавил в виде текста
